# Does Hibernate validate temporary tables?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

As my Spring application is starting up Hibernate is validating the MySQL schema of the database. One of the tables which is not mapped by my application is deleted by another application.

This results in an error (see below stacktrace) because a separate application using the same database is creating a "temporary" table without the `TEMPORARY` keyword. Thus as Hibernate begins to validate the schema the table `temp_pti_id` exists in the metadata information, and by the middle/end of validating the table no longer exists.

If we make `temp_pti_id` a `TEMPORARY` table will it be skipped by Hibernate schema validation altogether or do `TEMPORARY` tables count in the schema information being analyzed?

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: krfsPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing tables metadata
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing tables metadata
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.populateTablesWithColumns(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:383)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:337)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mydbname.temp_pti_id' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$2.forEach(DatabaseMetaData.java:2465)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData$2.forEach(DatabaseMetaData.java:2364)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.IterateBlock.doForAll(IterateBlock.java:50)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:2362)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.populateTablesWithColumns(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:350)
        ... 42 more
```

Comment: You should not be using transient/temporary tables to represent your entities.  But, AFAIK, if you Hibernate layer does not refer to a table in any way, there should be no problem.

Comment: I'm not using transient tables as this is not a table mapped by my application and is used by another application. Another application is interfering with my app. So there is a problem because there is a table being deleted in the middle of schema validation. It's not really to do with the mapping at all. Will `InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl` analyze temporary tables is my question.

I agree a table unrelated to my mappings should not interfere so I wonder if this is a bug with Hibernate in the end.